# copying ca to server for client authentication in mutual TLS?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am following [this](https://xrdocs.io/telemetry/tutorials/telemetry-stack-update-grpc-tls/) to configure TLS.

Article is too big, so summary is:

> Create CA.key, CA.pem using openssl
> Create key, certificate using openssl for server using above 2 and copy them to server
> Copy CA.pem on client to authenticate server certificate

[Here](https://xrdocs.io/telemetry/tutorials/telemetry-stack-update-grpc-tls/#:%7E:text=the%20Telegraf%20certificate-,Dial%2Din%20method,-For%20the%20dial:%7E:text=the%20Telegraf%20certificate-,Dial%2Din%20method,-For%20the%20dial), article tells that if mutual authentication is used, then generate certificate and key for client(using CA.key, CA.pem) and copy to client.

So my question is why don't we need to copy CA.pem to server, like we have to copy it on client? Else, how would server authenticate client certificate?

Comment: I'm not going to read that long article, but no matter what it says, yes, the CA certificate used to sign the TLS client certs must be available to and trusted by the TLS server.